# Radio Button Tag Helpers in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I don't see any tag helpers for radio buttons in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6. What's the right way of handling form elements where I need to use radio buttons?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

There is a TagHelper for all the input types which includes the radio button type as well. Assuming you have a view model like this

```
public class CreateUserVm
{
    public string UserName { set; get; }
    public IEnumerable<RoleVm> Roles { set; get; } 
    public int SelectedRole { set; get; }
}
public class RoleVm
{
    public int Id { set; get; }
    public string RoleName { set; get; }        
}
```

And in your GET action,

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var vm = new CreateUserVm
    {
        Roles = new List<RoleVm>
        {
            new RoleVm {Id = 1, RoleName = "Admin"},
            new RoleVm {Id = 2, RoleName = "Editor"},
            new RoleVm {Id = 3, RoleName = "Reader"}
        }
    };
    return View(vm);
}
```

In the view, You can simply use markup for the input tag.

```
@model YourNamespaceHere.CreateUserVm
<form asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home">
    <label class="label">User name</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="text" asp-for="UserName" />
    </div>
    <label class="label">Select a Role</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
    @foreach (var item in Model.Roles)
    {
       <input asp-for="SelectedRole" type="radio" value="@item.Id" /> @item.RoleName
    }
    </div>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When you post your form, The Rold Id for the selected role will be in the `SelectedRole` property

Keep in mind that, the above razor code will generate input element with **same** `Id` attribute value and `name` attribute value for each input generated by the loop. In the above example, it will generate 3 input elements(radio button type) with the `Id`  and `name` attribute value set to `SelectedRole`. Model binding will work as the `name` attribute value matches with the property name(`SelectedRole`) in our view model, but the duplicate Id attribute values might give you trouble with client side code (duplicate Ids in a document is invalid)

Comment: I'm using a JS click event on the radio button to submit to form, however the value from the radio is never being passed to my action method. Do I have to set the name or id attributes on the radio input to something specific?

Comment: Question: Could I set the value to be true or false? `value="true"`?

Comment: If that is what you want to pass when the radio button is selected

Comment: Doesn't this produce an error in browser console? with me ASP.Net core (as I think) generates the same Id for each radio input.

Comment: @MohammedNoureldin Yes. the tag helper generates same Id for all the input elements generated by the loop, which is invalid HTML! As of this moment, i do not know a clean solution to handle that. But model binding will work with the above approach as it only cares about the `name` attribute value of the inputs.

Comment: Apparently the work around now is to set the `id` html property manually to override tag helper behavior.

Comment: A snippit of the post code would be handy

Answer (score 8):

While there are solutions to use `asp-for="SomeField"`, I found that the easiest solution was to just match a view model field with the radio button's `name` field.

View Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public string MyRadioField { get; set; }
}
```

Form (without labels for clarity):

```
@model MyViewModel
<form asp-action="SomeAction" asp-controller="SomeController">
   <input type="radio" name="MyRadioField" value="option1" checked />
   <input type="radio" name="MyRadioField" value="option2" />
   <input type="radio" name="MyRadioField" value="option3" />

   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

When the form is submitted, `MyRadioField` is populated with value of the checked radio button.

Answer (score 0):

I've written my own tag helper to do that. It replaces the `input` tag with a label and a radiobutton for each enum variant:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using DigitScpi.Web.Helpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;

namespace TagHelpers
{
    /// Generates the radio buttons for an enum. Syntax: `<input radio asp-for="MyMappedEnumField"/>`.
    [HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = RadioAttributeName)]
    public class RadioButtonTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        private const string RadioAttributeName = "radio";
        private const string ForAttributeName = "asp-for";

        [HtmlAttributeNotBound] [ViewContext] public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }
        private readonly IHtmlGenerator _generator;

        [HtmlAttributeName(ForAttributeName)] public ModelExpression For { get; set; }
        [HtmlAttributeName(RadioAttributeName)] public bool RadioMarker { get; set; }

        public RadioButtonTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator)
        {
            _generator = generator;
        }

        /// <inheritdoc />
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.SuppressOutput();

            foreach (var enumItem in For.Metadata.EnumNamesAndValues)
            {
                var id = VariantId(enumItem);
                var name = For.Metadata.EnumGroupedDisplayNamesAndValues.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Value == enumItem.Value).Key.Name;
                var radio = _generator.GenerateRadioButton(ViewContext, For.ModelExplorer, For.Name, enumItem.Key, false, new {id});
                var label = _generator.GenerateLabel(ViewContext, For.ModelExplorer, For.Name, name, new {@for = id});

                output.PreElement.AppendHtml(radio);
                output.PreElement.AppendHtml(label);
            }
        }

        /// Computes the variant to be unique for each radiobutton.
        private string VariantId(KeyValuePair<string, string> enumItem) =>
            new StringBuilder()
                .Append(ViewContext.CreateUniqueId(_generator.IdAttributeDotReplacement, For.Name))
                .Append(_generator.IdAttributeDotReplacement)
                .Append(enumItem.Key)
                .ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension method that renders a radio button list given a SelectList.  You use it just like you use Html.DropDownListFor

```
public static HtmlString RadioButtonListFor<TModel, TResult>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TResult>> expression, SelectList selectList, string className = "radio-group")
{
  //render a list of radio buttons to bind to the specified value
  MemberExpression member = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
  string propertyName = member.Member.Name;

  Func<TModel, TResult> method = expression.Compile();
  TResult selectedValue = method(helper.ViewData.Model);

  var output = new StringBuilder();
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(className))
    output.AppendLine($"<div class='{className}'>");
  else
    output.AppendLine("<div>");

  foreach (SelectListItem item in selectList)
  {
    bool selected = Convert.ToString(selectedValue) == item.Value;
    string html = $"<label> <input type='radio' name='{propertyName}' value='{item.Value}' {(selected ? "checked" : "")} /> {item.Text} </label>";
    output.AppendLine(html);
  }
  output.AppendLine("</div>");

  return new HtmlString(output.ToString());
}
```

You call it like this in your razor file:

```
 @Html.RadioButtonListFor(m => m.ModelProperty, selectList)
```