# Is it possible to set radio button tag helper value attribute as "checked" in html?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, radio-button, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I was looking for a way to use the value attribute on radio button tag helper to inform if the button was checked or not, instead of using a separate field for selection. I found an answer by @Shyju to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34570908/radio-button-tag-helpers-in-asp-net-5-mvc-6). I am using a modified example of that answer to show what I mean.

Let's say I have a viewmodel

```
public class ExampleViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public List<UserRole> Roles { get; set; }
}
public class UserRole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

that is initialized in controller

```
public IActionResult Example()
    {
        var vm = new ExampleViewModel
        {
            Roles = new List<UserRole>
            {
                new UserRole {Id = 1, RoleName = "Admin"},
                new UserRole {Id = 2, RoleName = "Editor"},
                new UserRole {Id = 3, RoleName = "Reader"}
            }
        };
        return View("Example",vm);
    }
```

and used in view

```
<form asp-controller="Example" asp-action="Save">
    <label class="label">User name</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input asp-for="UserName" type="text" />
    </div>
    <label class="label">Select a Role</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Roles.Count; i++)
            {
                <label class="btn btn-default">
                    <input asp-for="Roles[i].Id" type="radio" value="@Model.Roles[i].Id" />
                    <input asp-for="Roles[i].IsSelected" type="radio" value=true />
                    @Model.Roles[i].RoleName
                </label>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

What I would like to achieve with this, is to be able to read the UserRole.IsSelected field in controller's post method to see if the particular UserRole was checked or not. This solution works if the user checks only one button and does not alter the choice. If the user changes selection to another, then all UserRole values the user has touched will have the IsSelected field as true.

Is it possible to somehow set the IsSelected value with HTML to show only the button that is checked when the form is submitted or does it require a JavaScript function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your models do not make sense for radio buttons (which are for choosing one from many). If you want to select only one role, then you models need to be

```
public class ExampleViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int SelectedRole { get; set; }
    public List<UserRole> RolesList { get; set; }
}
public class UserRole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
}
```

and in the view

```
@foreach(var role < Model.RolesList)
{
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input asp-for=SelectedRole" type="radio" value="role.Id" />
        <span>@role.RoleName<span>
    </label>
}
```

and in the POST method, the value of `SelectedRole` will contain the `Id` of the selected `UserRole`

If alternatively, you want to select multiple roles, the use you existing models, but the view becomes

```
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Roles.Count; i++)
{
    <label class="btn btn-default">
        <input asp-for="Roles[i].Id" type="hidden"/>
        <input asp-for="Roles[i].IsSelected" type="checkbox"/>
        <span>@Model.Roles[i].RoleName</span>
    </label>
}
```

and in the POST method, you can get the selected roles using

```
IEnumerable<UserRole> selectedRoles = model.Roles.Where(x => x.IsSelected);
```

Comment: Thanks Stephen, your answer is very clear and informative. I am trying to develop a solution where I could set the selection criteria dynamically in the view. Sometimes the selection would be exclusive one only (radio button) and sometimes multiple choices would be allowed (checkbox). I could then use the same model in both cases. I had a feeling it might not be possible, but I thought I'd ask it here to be sure.

Comment: Not at all. It was a good answer to my question, which probably was a bit too precise. Implicitly it solved my problem.

Comment: @StephenMuecke In my case I was placing an extra attribute `name=RoleType` inside `<input asp-for=SelectedRole" type="radio" value="role.Id" />` and was always getting the value of radio button as null. But after reading your post, I realized that if using tag helper I don't need to use name attribute since `asp-for` automatically generates name and id attributes for us. After reading your post I removed the name attribute and it's working now. Thanks for putting all necessary code and a brief explanation of it.