# How to get hard coded value of selected Radio Button tag helper on Form Post

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

Is the above possible without defining a property in a `ViewModel` that holds the value of the `value attribute` of `input` tag of type `radio`. For instance, in the following `view`, I would like `SelectedOrderType` property to hold 1 if user selects `In-Store` radio button, and hold 2 if `Online` radio button is selected.
But when the form is submitted, `SelectedOrderType` property always holds the value 1 regardless of which radio button was selected. **Note**: When form is loaded, by default first radio button is checked. But user, of course, can check any of the two before submitting the form. **NOTE** 2: Form is submitted via an Ajax call inside the `view` below:

**View with Form with Radio Button tag helper**:

```
@model TestProj.Models.TestViewModel

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Add Order</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane in active">
        <form asp-controller="TestContrl" asp-action="TestAction" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input asp-for="SelectedOrderType" type="radio" value="1" checked="checked">In-Store</label>
            </div>
            <div class="radio">
                <label><input asp-for="SelectedOrderType" type="radio" value="2">Online</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                ....
                ....
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">Submit Order</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
 </div>


@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.tab-content').on('click', '.btn', function (event) {

                var selectedOrderTypeVal = $('#SelectedOrderType').val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("TestContrl", "TestAction")',
                    data: { SelectedOrderType: selectedOrderTypeVal },
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#menu1').html(data);
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                        alert('jqXHR.statusCode');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

**View Model**:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
     public string SelectedOrderType { get; set; }

     public string CustormerName{ get; set; }
}
```

**Snapshot of the generated Html of the View**:

```
<html>
....
<div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" value="1" checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The SelectedProjType field is required."
    id="SelectedOrderType" name="SelectedOrderType">In-Store</label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
        <label><input type="radio" value="2" id="SelectedOrderType" name="SelectedOrderType">Online</label>
</div>
....
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code in my Ajax code above was the issue.

```
var selectedOrderTypeVal = $('#SelectedOrderType').val();
```

It should be the following as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23053203/1232087):

```
var selectedProjTypeVal = $('[name=SelectedProjType]:checked').val();
```

**Also of interests** [In case you want to use ViewModels]:

1. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38471850/1232087)
2. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34571420/1232087)