# C# & ASP.NET MVC : how to pass a form radio button value to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a C# ASP.NET MVC application where I display a form with a set of radio buttons.

The html markup looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("RequestReport", "SponsorReports", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="text" class="hidden" value="114" id="FormReportNumber" name="FormReportNumber" asp-for="FormReportNumber"/>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="input_from" class="">Enter the FROM date (in MM/DD/YYYY format)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_from" placeholder="From Date" name="Input_From" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="input_to" class="">Enter the Through date (in MM/DD/YYYY format)</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input_to"   placeholder="Through Date" name="Input_To" value="">
    </div>
    <hr />
    <b>How would you like the report sorted?</b>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" value="mid" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="FormReportSort1" checked />
        <label class="form-check-label font-weight-normal" for="FormReportSort1">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sorted by MID
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" value="last" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="FormReportSort2" />
        <label class="form-check-label font-weight-normal" for="FormReportSort2">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Sorted by Last Name
        </label>
    </div>
    <hr />

    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" 
            type="submit" id="submitButton" 
            onclick="return DisplayProgressMessage(this, 'Submit');">Submit</button>
}
```

I have a model class which looks like this:

```
    public int FormReportNumber { get; set; } = 0;
    public string Input_From { get; set; }
    public string Input_To { get; set; }
    public string FormReportSort1 { get; set; }
    public string FormReportSort2 { get; set; }
```

When the page is presented and I enter values into the 2 date boxes and click the submit button, the form is submitted to the controller.

I have the following code in my controller:

```
public IActionResult RequestReport(string reportNumber, Sponsor_TotalViewData formData)
{
    TempData.Keep("SponsorSessionData");
}
```

When I set a breakpoint on the `TempData.Keep` statement and I view the variable `formData`, I see the values of `formData.Input_From` and `formData.Input_To`. I also see the value of `formData.FormReportNumber`. These values got passed from the form.  However I do not see the values passed from the radio buttons.

How do I set this up to pass the value 'mid' if the user clicks on the radio button with `id="FormReportSort1"`? How do I set this up to pass the value 'last' if the user clicks on the radio button with `id="FormReportSort2"`?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you have two Properties backing the radio control? The form values bind by matching the `name` attribute. Reduce your model to `string FormReportSort` and the radio selection would give `FormReportSort` the selected value. See some examples here https://stackoverflow.com/q/34570908/2030565

Comment: @Jasen I reduced my model and changed the name and id of the radio button.  Now, the selected button's value is passed back to the controller.  Thank you so much!

Comment: That is something from 6 years ago, sometimes these answers don't apply to the way you do it now @Jasen. I have had this issue before, I was trying to do it the same way as them and it didn't work.